# What could be the reasons for JsonMappingException?

Tags: apache-spark, jackson

Get an exception while the Spark (3.0.1) application is running:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module 2.10.0 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.10.0 and < 2.11.0
```

I have already seen questions with a similar Jackson error, but they are different from my case: these Jackson dependencies are already match up and should be compatible:

```
[Driver] INFO ru.kontur.srs.infra.launching.daemon.DaemonLauncher$ - /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/SrsApp/filecache/4368/__spark_libs__4872112349984824286.zip/jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar
[Driver] INFO ru.kontur.srs.infra.launching.daemon.DaemonLauncher$ - /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/SrsApp/filecache/4368/__spark_libs__4872112349984824286.zip/jackson-core-2.10.0.jar
[Driver] INFO ru.kontur.srs.infra.launching.daemon.DaemonLauncher$ - /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/SrsApp/filecache/4368/__spark_libs__4872112349984824286.zip/jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar
[Driver] INFO ru.kontur.srs.infra.launching.daemon.DaemonLauncher$ - /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/SrsApp/filecache/4368/__spark_libs__4872112349984824286.zip/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.10.0.jar
[Driver] INFO ru.kontur.srs.infra.launching.daemon.DaemonLauncher$ - /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/SrsApp/filecache/4368/__spark_libs__4872112349984824286.zip/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.3.jar
[Driver] INFO ru.kontur.srs.infra.launching.daemon.DaemonLauncher$ - /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/SrsApp/filecache/4368/__spark_libs__4872112349984824286.zip/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.0.jar
[Driver] INFO ru.kontur.srs.infra.launching.daemon.DaemonLauncher$ - /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/SrsApp/filecache/4368/__spark_libs__4872112349984824286.zip/jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.0.jar
[Driver] INFO ru.kontur.srs.infra.launching.daemon.DaemonLauncher$ - /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/SrsApp/filecache/4368/__spark_libs__4872112349984824286.zip/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.10.0.jar
```

[image]
[image]

I double-checked it even in this way:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // ...
    
    logger.info("JACKSON VERSION: " + new ObjectMapper().version())
   
    // ...
}

> [Driver] INFO ru.kontur.khajiit.reports.builders.raw_products.ReportsRawProductsReportBuilderDaemon$ - JACKSON VERSION: 2.10.0
```

What could be the reasons that `2.10` does not pass the `>= 2.10.0 and < 2.11.0` check and how can this problem be solved?